# Windows 7 Black screen of death after RAM upgrade

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

A co-worker of mine upgraded his pc to 4 gigs of ram from 2.

After installing the new RAM his computer boots ok, he gets to the login screen, logs in fine, and then his computer screen goes black with just an active mouse cursor.

Running in safe mode works fine.

Update 1:

Safemode with Networking has the same black screen with active mouse.
Safemode correctly reports the machine having 4 gigs installed.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

- Remove the new RAM stick
- Update the motherboards bios
- See if it boots normally after the update
- Reinstall the additional RAM and see if it still boots

Comment: I would actually remove the RAM first, then try to reboot normally before the BIOS update. Just to change one thing at a time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I'm wondering if the system applied some updates during the shutdown/reboot?

The Windows 7 Black Screen of Death is pretty well documented. It *could* be tied to the RAM install, but maybe not. I like Ivo's suggestion here!

Here's some information on the KSoD:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/01/windows-7-black-screen-of-death-fix/